# D3 - How to convert circle-pack to ellipse-pack?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

How to utilize `D3` circle pack layout to get diagram similar to this:

[image]

(even with more elongated ellipses)?

The key aplication of this diagram style would be easier label placement.

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/WDCpq/8/) that demonstrates circle pack, that I made for other purposes, but I guess it might be useful starting point for anyone wanting to experiment and test potential solution involving ellipses.

---

Based on @Mariatta 's answer, I got [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Upt3h/1/):

[image]

But I was hoping I would preserve parent-children visual connection.

---

In the second attempt, I got what I want ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Upt3h/2/)):

[image]

The key was to change `cy` of the ellipses the same way as `ry`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the part you need to pay attention to is :

```
var circles = vis.append("circle")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return !d.children ? "tan" : "beige"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });
```

What happens here is you are creating an svg circle element with attributes of cx, cy, and r, similar to `<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />`

To convert this to ellipsis, you need to know what are the attributes you need to set. An svg ellipse element can be created like so:
`<ellipse cx="200" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50">`
Note how you need to set the `cx`, `cy`, `rx`, and `ry` as opposed to `cx`, `cy`, and `r` for `<circle>`

Based on this knowledge you should be now able to convert your circle to ellipse like this :

```
var ellipses = vis.append("ellipse")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return !d.children ? "tan" : "beige"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("rx", 10) // define your own rule for x radius
    .attr("ry", 5); // define your own rule for y radius
```